# How to know submit function is working or not with click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the value once the form is submitted by using submit() jquery function and also trying to alert the particular value but going in vain...
here is my code

```
 $('.saving_account .list-radio').click(function() {
   $('.saving_account .selected_radio').removeClass('selected_radio');
   $(this).toggleClass('selected_radio'); 

   $('input[type="radio"]').prop("checked", false);
   $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').prop("checked", true);
   //submit action
   $('form#target').submit(function() {
 alert( $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').val());
});
// alert( $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').val());

   });
```

jsfiddle url
    https://jsfiddle.net/y3axmsah/1/

Comment: You need to prevent form submition first: `$('form#target').submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ....}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: `fiddle.jshell.net/y3axmsah/1/show/:84 Uncaught ReferenceError: onButtonClick is not defined`

Comment: i need on click of list (li) it should call the submit function and the value in alert

Answer (score 2):

The button with `type="submit"` will submit the form and you can't see any results. You need to prevent form submission jQuery way:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    /* your code */
});
```

or simply by returning `true` or `false` in submit event:

```js
 $('#target').submit(function(e) {
     var thisForm = $(this);
     var checkedRadio = thisForm.find('input:checked');
     if (confirm('Selected value is: ' + checkedRadio.val() +', continue?')) {
         return true;
     } else {
         return false;
     }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="saving_account live-search-list">
    <form id="target">
        <li class="list-radio">
            <input type="radio" name="bankname" value="hdfc" checked> sample text</li>
        <li class="list-radio">
            <input type="radio" name="bankname" value="hdfc1"> sample text1
        </li>
        <li class="list-radio">
            <input type="radio" name="bankname" value="hdfc2"> sample text2
        </li>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn_green" id="bank527">CONTINUE</button>
    </form>
</ul>
```

Also on **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3axmsah/2/)**

Comment: Note: `return false` and `e.preventDefault();` [do not do the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/542251)

Comment: i need on click of list (li) it should call the submit function and the value in alert

Answer (score 0):

for submit form

change

```
$('#bank527').submit();
```

to

```
$('#target').submit();
```

Comment: i need on click of list (li) it should call the submit function and the value in alert